# Is there a way to detect an elements height before its rendered in the before input event

Tags: javascript, contenteditable, lit

I have content editable below and an onbeforeinput event listener and function. Using lit.js I want to get the paragraph or h1 element before it hits the dom. So I can get its height and width to see if it has exceeded the divs bounds. When I get the e.target in the before input event all it shows is the div editor as the target.

```
<div class="editor" contenteditable="true"  @beforeinput='${this._beforeInput}'  placeholder="TR"></div>

_beforeInput(e) {
    console.log('before input ',e);
    
  }
```

I would like to get the height and width of the incoming h1 or p elements.

Comment: I don't know anything about lit.js but had had a similar situation in JS in trying to make a textarea grow and shrink as text was input or removed and, ultimately, it was done using an off-screen element that was a copy of the on-screen div, putting the information in it, and getting its size. This [MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTextAreaElement#examples) might be useful if you have to take that approach.

Comment: thank you it put me in the right direction